# PCI compliant transparent data encryption at disk/folder level on Windows?

Tags: encryption, windows, pci-dss

Is there a way to achieve PCI compliant data encryption at disk/folder level in Windows in a way that is transparent to applications(they must be able to write/read to encrypted folders/disks as if they weren't encrypted)?

How should the keys be managed (regarding for example key rotation)?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows [Encrypting File System (EFS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700811.aspx) would meet your usability requirements and probably the majority, if not all, of the PCI DSS requirements.  However, I have not evaluated it against the DSS so I can't say for sure.

You could turn on EFS for a directory structure and then point all your applications to write to subdirectories within that tree.  Windows handles all the file encryption behind the scenes so the applications aren't aware of it.

You shouldn't need to rotate encryption keys often if the keys were strong (e.g. long enough) to begin with.  Typically you should change them only after an employee with access to them left, or you believe they were potentially compromised.  Otherwise you shouldn't really need to change keys more than every few years or so.

EFS works a bit differently because every file is encrypted with its own key and then those keys are managed using asymmetric encryption.  With EFS you have certs associated with public/private key pairs that you have to add or remove from EFS policies if you want to make changes to who can decrypt data.

Comment: Requirement 3.4.1.a states If disk encryption is used, verify that logical access to encrypted file systems is implemented via a mechanism that is separate from the native operating systems mechanism (for example, not using local user account databases)." From what I gather for windows efs decrypting credentials are not different from windows login credentials, and so it's not compliant?

Comment: @mic.sca I looked at that section of the standard and it distinguishes between "disk encryption" and "file-level encryption", but appears to apply only to disk encryption.  EFS is file-level encryption, not full disk encryption, so this section may not be relevant.  However, the description of what they're trying to avoid (decryption keys unlinked from user accounts) is an inherent part of using EFS, so it might violate the policy intent.  You'd probably want a QSA to bless using EFS first if that's your only encryption in use.